# View event details in "Events Detail View" in Windows Server 2012

Tags: logging, windows-server-2012, windows

Is there a way to actually view the details of an event in the "Events Detail View" that's provided by the Windows Server 2012 Server Manager?

[image: Events Detail View in Server Manager]

Answer (score 1):

Method 1:

1. Highlight the event in which you are interested
2. Click "Go to Hyper-V" (it may also be "Go to Local Server", depending on the context)
3. Scroll down to the "Events" section.  Now that you are in the context of the particular machine, you will be able to see the event details.

Method 2:

Log in to the machine that is the source of the event (e.g. "DEEPTHOUGHT").  Go to the start screen, type "Event Viewer".  Once the event viewer opens, the events will be in the log listed under "log" in your screen shot (e.g. "Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-Worker-Admin").